# Why we need to use Static keyword inside Static class?

Tags: c#, .net, static

> All members must be explicitly specified as static, static class does not automatically make its members static. Static class can contain a collection of static methods.

The definition explains all i.e we need to explicitly give static for methods , members etc inside static class .

What i really didn't get here is if there is a rule like we can declare only  static members inside a static class

why doesn't the developer of `OOPL` make it `not mandate` . so the compiler should understand(internally) i.e even if we declare a non-static method inside a static class it should understand the method as `static` (i.e static class can only have static methods) .

I got this doubt when i am working on interfaces see even in case of interfaces all interfaces members are `public` so we don't declare then public `explicitly` compiler will understand internally .

All i am looking is for a big `WHY` not for excuses(it should be like that , its in-build functionality).

Comment: there should be duplicate of this somewhere... this is a design decision so we can't answer WHY because we are not designers of the language.

Comment: I like dav_i's answer. On your point about members being public implicitly, that is true but public is the default whereas static is never the default.

Comment: `selman22` that was fact i'm looking why they done that . `dav_i` looks intresting . `downvote` sad , i didnt get why excatly . please do comment so i can correct myself (if there is possible chance) . i'm looking for something i dont know . cheers

Answer (score 0):

I imagine because a) it is easier to see and b) is consistent:

#### Easier to see

```
public static class WithoutStaticMembers
{
    public string GetString() // easy to miss that it is static
    {
        return "string";
    }
}

public static class WithStaticMembers
{
    public static string GetString() // clearly static
    {
        return "string";
    }
}
```

#### Consistant

```
public class NotStaticClass
{
    public static string GetString()
    {
        return "string";
    }
}

public static class StaticClass
{
    public static string GetString()
    {
        return "string";
    }
}
// ...
var s1 = NotStaticClass.GetString();
var s2 = StaticClass.GetString(); // consistent across both static class and not static
```